# Comparing numbers with awk

Tags: shell, awk

EDIT: found the answer thanks to James Brown, there was a problem in the way I formatted the command:

```
awk -F"," '{ if ($2*$3 > 0.5) print }'
```

is working.

I've got a file like this:

```
1000,0.5,1
2000,0.5,3
4000,1,3
5000,0.2,1
```

I need to multiply $2 and $3 for each line and check if the result is superior to 0.5.
I read that the -gt operator cannot handle floating-point numbers and that awk could do it.

Here's the best I could come up with:

```
cat awk.txt | awk -F"," '{ if ("$2"*"$3" > "0,5") print "$line"}'
```

Of course, it doesn't work, but it doesn't return any error...

Expected result:

```
5000,0.2,1
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much

Comment: `"$2"` is literal string `$2`, not the value of the second field, as is `"$line"` and `"0,5"` - also notice that you have comma in it and that is not the decimal separator. To `print` the line, just use `print`. Also, no need for `cat file`, awk can process files with `awk '...' file`.

Comment: cat awk.txt | awk -F"," '{ if ($2*$3 > "0,5") print }'  is working, thanks to you James Brown.

Comment: awk is not shell, it's a completely different language, like C, with it's own syntax and semantics.

Comment: Regarding `EDIT: found the answer...` - no, that script, `awk -F"," '{ if ($2*$3 > "0,5") print }'` is doing a string comparison, not a numeric one. The fact you're getting the expected output is just coincidence, try `echo 11 | awk '{ if ($1 > "2") print }'` and you'll see it outputs nothing. You're also using `,` in that code as the decimal point but `.` in your data - the decimal point in your locale can't be both a comma and a period.

Comment: You're right, it's because we use '0,5' and not '0.5' in French language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing the errors in your code:

```
$ awk -F"," '{if($2*$3 > 0.5) print}' file
```

output is:

```
2000,0.5,3
4000,1,3
```

You could also just:

```
$ awk -F, '$2*$3>0.5' file
```

Answer (score 2):

> Of course, it doesn't work, but it doesn't return any error...

I want to explain what actually happend

```
awk -F"," '{ if ("$2"*"$3" > "0,5") print "$line"}'
```

first thing is multiplying string `$2` by string `$3`, this prompt GNU AWK to convert both of them to numbers as described in [How awk Converts Between Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html) as neither string as whole or any prefix is valid number following does apply

> Strings that can’t be interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero.

therefore you got in fact following multiplication

```
0*0
```

which yields number 0, which in turn gives following comparison

```
0 > "0,5"
```

which again prompt conversion of string to number, which gives `0` as `0` is longest number-constituting prefix of `0,5`, so finally we get

```
0 > 0
```

which does never holds, so you get empty output.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F',' -lane'print if $F[1]*$F[2]>0.5' file


perl -lne'($a,$b)=((split/,/)[1,2]);print if $a*$b>0.5' file
```